# Automatically switch JDK/JRE version using ANT

Tags: java, unix, ant, javac

Currently I have a Java project which requires JRE 1.8. An ANT build script is used to compile the project using the `javac` task as follows:

```
<javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/build/src" destdir="build/build/classes" encoding="UTF-8">
```

This works perfectly when run on a computer using JRE 1.8, however I am now looking to run the script on a computer with JRE 1.7 set as the default. JRE 1.8 is available on this computer in the `/opt` directory and the installation is listed when `whereis javac` is run.

Is there a way to configure the script to use JRE 1.8 automatically, using the JRE 1.8 installation files located in the `/opt` directly? Ideally the script would revert the default version back to 1.7 after the application is run.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `executable` attribute can be used to tell `javac` which compiler to use. This attribute requires `fork=yes`, i.e. the compiler will run in a separate process (more information [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)):

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
     destdir="${build}"
     fork="yes"
     executable="/opt/java/jdk1.8/bin/javac"
     compiler="javac1.8"
/>
```